# How to log connection pool information for HttpClient in .NET 5 with HttpClientFactory.?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I am using HttpClient with HttpClientFactory in .Net 5

```
services.AddHttpClient("BasicUsage", c =>
                     {
                        // c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30);
                     }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
                     {
                         AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                         AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
                         UseCookies = true,
                         UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                         SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11,
                         ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; },
                         MaxAutomaticRedirections = 5,
                         CookieContainer = cookies,
                     });
```

I have used Nlog for logging with ILogger

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                    {
                        // configure Logging with NLog
                        loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                        loggingBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                        loggingBuilder.AddNLog(config);
                    });
```

I am getting request and response details and duration of it in log. But I want to write connection timing details in my log something like chrome provides :-

[image]

Comment: There is nothing that granular out of the box. If you want something as granular as chrome, well this question because too broad or asking for a library, this would request some serious socket level handler work. If you want simplistic timing and custom logging, its easy enough to write your self Delegating handler and an `IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter` to make it global

Comment: arg... because = becomes

Comment: @TheGeneral I am looking IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter in detail. Hope I can found something. Thanks...

Comment: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging this basically how the default log factory works

Comment: Reading the source, it looks like `HttpTelemetry` exists for this purpose. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/68c0055ff08da5c9fe5bd8fb2b3993a9ceb03828/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L406 Maybe this is more useful? https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/additional-http-sockets-dns-and-tls-telemetry-in-dotnet-5